# Is there some C preprocessor that would lift requirement to pass `this` to virtual method?

Tags: c, object, this, c-preprocessor

I'm implementing a neo-fork of [Midnight Commander](https://github.com/neo-mc/neo-mc) in a style resembling OO programming. It's however little irritating to pass the object as the first argument for virtual methods. I wonder if there is a C pre-processor that would be lifting this requirement? E.g.: that would translate some special dereference operator:

```
object-->method(a, b, c);
```

into:

```
object->method(object, a, b, c)
```

? It is so simple task that I could even be implementing it by myself. However, is there a ready to use preprocessor?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but experience have thought me that code generation to be an evil leaky and usually bloated abstraction. It leaves you with a custom language no one else knows.  If you want to emulate the C++ style well just use the real thing.  I prefer the normal C-style class_method(object, ...) and find little value in stuffing function pointers into to your object.

Comment: @AllanWind: it could work also for non-virtual functions, e.g.: `object→method(a.b,c)` would translate to: `method(object,a,b,c)` – just one more (and last) special dereference operator.

Comment: Why not use C++?

Comment: I think that C++ is a bloated langue. The so many template-exaggerations introduced in recent years – I like C for its simplicity.

Comment: btw... `a-->b` will actually work in C as `(a--) > b`

Comment: You don't have to use the extra features you don't want. Nothing stops you from writing in "C with classes".

Comment: C++ is predicated on its features being zero cost if you don't use them.

Comment: @tstanisl Yes, that is the (in)famous "downto operator" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c :D

Answer (score 3):

What you suggest is done by any C++ compiler (for `virtual` member functions).

So a possible approach could be to transform your C code into C++ code. In many cases, it is easy (since C++ was designed, 20 years ago, as a superset of C. It later evolved independently).

You could also consider writing your C code generator (technically, a [translator](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) from your dialect to C), with a parser developed with [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](http://antlr.org).

Look also into the Gobject layer of [GTK](https://gtk.org/). It could be inspirational (and GTK is open source)

If you develop your own programming dialect, please document it well (with [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) for syntax).

Another approach might be to *embed* some *existing* interpreter (like [Lua](https://lua.org/), [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/), [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), etc...) in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You could try following macro:

```
#define CALL(OBJ, METHOD, ...) (OBJ)->METHOD(OBJ, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Now the call:

```
CALL(object, method, a, b, c)
```

expands as:

```
object->method(object, a, b, c)
```

The issue is that at the method must take at least two arguments (`object` and something). Otherwise the compiler will complain about extra `,`. There exist methods to lift this limitation but they are either compiler specific or very tricky.

Comment: Thanks. It's an interesting option. It isn't as simple as -> operator, however I think that it could be a good solution, resembling Objective C messages… I could write a similar macro `MESSAGE(object,method,…)` and also a non-virtual macro `#define MESSAGE2(OBJ, METHOD, ...) (METHOD(OBJ,## __VA_ARGS__)` so that non-virtual methods would have been covered… I wonder if an automatic detection of virtual methods could be created? I can use some GCC builtins, no problem. Macro should detect if there is a field of name of method, I think. Or detect if object is a struct, maybe?

Comment: @psprint, what about wrapping virtual calls as non-virtual ```ret_type obj_method(struct obj* x, ...) { return x->method(x, ...); }``` and using only `MESSAGE2`-like macro ?